# What is the proper term for these items/images

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, lists

First, is there any generic term or style for this type of showcasing images/items in mobile? I'm trying to emulate the style used here but first I would like to know the proper team so that we could search if there is any library built already and avoid reinventing the wheel.

[image: Screenshot of said layout]

[image: Another screenshot]

I could build something like this in mobile app (react-native), but it would be too rigid, like it would be a rows/columns of fixed images but it is no way closer than this where images have their own sizes and it seems not following the traditional row/column grid structure.

Comment: FYI, your question #2 is about implementation, which is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: tnx for noting that out,, fixed :)

Answer (score 8):

I've seen it referred to as [Masonry Layout](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/). As popularized by Pinterest.

Comment: The individual components are called "cards" in Material and Bootstrap as well. Perhaps that will help your search.